# css menu sliding subelements hide when hover instead of changing color

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, web-frontend

Yesterday i found a code for making sliding menu only with css.
Everything works great when in my css file i set styles for all ul,li,a elements.
The problem appears when i try to style lists in concrete div,then when i hover on the top element,sub elements appear but when i try to point on them they hide [working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUun7.png) [it_hides_when_hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Advur.png).
Can anyone explain why in div it doesn't work ?

```css
#nav  ul {
 list-style-type:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 position: absolute;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
  #nav li {
 display:inline-block;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 1px;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
#nav li a {
 display:block;
 min-width:140px;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 50px;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 background: #2f3036;
 text-decoration: none;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
#nav  li:hover a {
 background: #19c589;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/
#nav li:hover ul a {
 background: #f3f3f3;
 color: #2f3036;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
#nav li:hover ul a:hover {
 background: #19c589;
 color: #fff;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
#nav  li ul {
 display: none;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
#nav li ul li {
 display: block;
 float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
#nav li ul li a {
 width: auto;
 min-width: 100px;
 padding: 0 20px;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
#nav ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2">
<TITLE>Tytuł strony!</TITLE>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
<META NAME="description" CONTENT="Site description">
<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="ALL">
 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nav">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">GALERRY</a>
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li><a href="#">ConceptArt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
                
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">INFO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a>
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li><a href="#">We do</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">We are</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
           
        </ul>
        
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modified example:

http://codepen.io/xvariant/pen/pgKxwp

```css
#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/

#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
/*Style for menu links*/

#nav li a {
  display: block;
  min-width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background: #2f3036;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*Hover state for top level links*/

#nav li:hover a {
  background: #19c589;
}
/*Style for dropdown links*/

#nav li:hover ul a {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  color: #2f3036;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
/*Hover state for dropdown links*/

#nav li:hover ul a:hover {
  background: #19c589;
  color: #fff;
}
/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/

#nav li ul {
  display: none;
}
/*Make dropdown links vertical*/

#nav li ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}
/*Prevent text wrapping*/

#nav li ul li a {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
/*Display the dropdown on hover*/

#nav ul li:hover .hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">GALERRY</a>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li><a href="#">ConceptArt</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Videos</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">INFO</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li><a href="#">We do</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">We are</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Your css was for `a:hover` instead of the li that contains both the button and the sub-items. I put `display: block` on `hidden` ul within the `li:hover`. The li contains the sub-items as well. This way when the cursor is on anywhere in that li, the sub-items will be visible.

Comment: `#nav ul li:hover .hidden {
  display: block;
}`
This is the modified part.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your style `ul#menu li:hover .hidden{display:block}`

Comment: it worked thanks a lot, but could you explain why it didn't work earlier ?

Comment: The code ul#menu li:hover .hidden{display:block} was missing